# Insert data in Firebase in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

During storing an object to my firebase, I am expecting the structure as image below, but what I get was a generated running number as a key. This is my code to store an object to firebase

```
var location = [];
location.push({
  ms_jhr_1 : {
    name: value
  },
  ...
});
const a = firebase.database().ref('Food/'+id);
a.set(location);
```

[image: Expected structure]

How do I keep my structure without generate the running number?

Comment: Firebase doesn't store arrays, only maps.  The key names need to be unique. I would restructure `location = {}` and use `Object.assign(location, newData)`.  If you have to have an array, then you are going to need to use `Array.reduce` to create a map to send to firebase.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are using an array to store your data and then setting that array in firebase. To get the expected result you have to modify your code a little bit.

Here use this and remove other code

```
const a = firebase.database().ref('Food/'+id);
a.set(ms_jhr_1);
```

So you just need to pass the object you want to store under that id and not the whole array.

Note:- If you want to store multiple entries under one id then you have to push all those entries in an Object and not in array.

So it will look something like this

```
var location = {};
```

Now use for loop to insert all your data into this object (Remember, you are adding objects inside an object). You don't need array. Because in firebase data is stored in JSON tree format.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `var location = {};` still generate a key number if i use `location.push..` to push multiple object inside it.

Comment: Don't use .push method, it is used for array. Just use for loop to insert data into location object. You can use for in loop to add object inside an object.

Comment: Great answer @PradhumnSharma! Firebase Database indeed stores arrays as objects with keys `0`, `1`, etc. It sounds like ggDeGreat wants an object/set instead of an array, so getting rid of the array (and calls to `push()`) is the way to go. Another way to initialize the `location` object is: `location.ms_jhr_1 = { name: value }` or `location["ms_jhr_1"] = { name: value }`.